# converting to a pandas dataframe with numpy dtype of string

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, numpy

This is a super basic question but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.  I've looked at the docs and on Stack Overflow. I need to get a numpy array of strings which I will then save as a csv. I have a line like this:

```
np.savetxt(path + 'section.csv', np.asarray(seclist, dtype=np.dtype('a2')), fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

and it returns an error:

> ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence.

If I remove `dtype`, it works fine except it prints objects formatted as strings so each item has a bracket and `''` around it.  When I try `dtype=string` that does not work it gives me an error:

> TypeError: data type not understood.

I've tried `dtype='string'`, `dtype = np.str`, `dtype = np.str_` and quite a few more but none of them get the `dtype` to be string.  Any help would be appreciated,

Cameron

Comment: What datatype is seclist? When I try it out on a list of string literals it works.

Comment: It's a list of mostly empty lists as I am just testing out the code. But it has a few characters like 'G' etc.  Maybe I need to use the char datatype, I'll think about that.

Comment: The problem is that its a list of lists with stings as elements.  When I do save text it doesn't recognize that I want to save the string just the list.  I'm looking into how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a python list of lists.  However some lists were length 0 and some were length 1.  Thus the numpy couldn't accept the string dtype.  When I padded the lists so they were all the same length that fixed everything.

Comment: If this answer fixes your problem, you should probably accept your own answer.